# Using XSLT to split duplicate text() and group non-duplicates together

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following input XML:

```
<root>
    <element>
          <id>1</id>
          <text><![CDATA[My text 1]]></text>
    </element>
    <element>
          <id>2</id>
          <text><![CDATA[My text 1]]></text>
    </element>
    <element>
          <id>3</id>
          <text><![CDATA[My text 2]]></text>
    </element>
    <element>
          <id>4</id>
          <text><![CDATA[My text 2]]></text>
    </element>
    <element>
          <id>5</id>
          <text><![CDATA[My text 3]]></text>
    </element>
</root>
```

I'm looking to transform this using XSLT 2.0, to split duplicate text() in the text element and group my non-duplicates together into separate files (**for any number of duplicates** - my example only shows two). So I should have no duplicate text() in any of my output files, and they need to be grouped into as few files as possible. My output from the above should look like this:

**document1.xml**

```
<root>
    <element>
          <id>1</id>
          <text><![CDATA[My text 1]]></text>
    </element>
    <element>
          <id>3</id>
          <text><![CDATA[My text 2]]></text>
    </element>
    <element>
          <id>5</id>
          <text><![CDATA[My text 3]]></text>
    </element>
</root>
```

**document2.xml**

```
<root>
    <element>
          <id>2</id>
          <text><![CDATA[My text 1]]></text>
    </element>
    <element>
          <id>4</id>
          <text><![CDATA[My text 2]]></text>
    </element>
</root>
```

My existing XSLT snippet looks like this: I get the feeling I need to collect my duplicates together in my for-each-group (in order to split by position), but obviously this results in one file per element:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::element" group-by="text[text() = preceding::text/text() or text() = following::text/text()]">
            <xsl:result-document href="{concat($outputdir,'\document',position(),'.xml')}" method="xml" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="text">
        <root>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>   
        </root>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Appreciate any help you're able to offer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your input and outputs aren't in sync.. Could you please take a look and explain the logic more clearly.

Comment: Thanks for the spot: I've updated the IDs to make it more accurate. So I have no duplicate <text> in any of my output files, and they're grouped into as few files as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following looks rather like an imperative solution done with XSLT but I think it does the job:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:variable name="groups">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="element" group-by="text">
      <group key="{current-grouping-key()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
      </group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="max-size" select="max($groups/group/count(element))"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="1 to $max-size">
    <xsl:result-document href="document{.}.xml">
      <root>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$groups/group/element[position() eq current()]"/>
      </root>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Excellent solution, works perfectly and covers all my requirements. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:call-template name="out">
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="root" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="out">
        <xsl:param name="root"/>
        <xsl:param name="level"/>

        <xsl:if test="$root/*">
            <xsl:result-document href="document{$level}.xml">
                <root>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="$root/*" group-by="text">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </root>
            </xsl:result-document>

            <xsl:call-template name="out">
                <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level+1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="root">
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="$root/*" group-by="text">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[. != current()]"/>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```